# Clean Architecture: User entity and Foreign keys

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I'm in the exactly same situation of this question:
[User entity in Clean Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63956730/user-entity-in-clean-architecture)

The reccomended answer suggests to reference a user entity in some domain entity by using a unique identifier (e.g. a GUID). Let's suppose to use a integer Id.

I'm worried about a simple consequence of this reccomandation:
doing this way, there is no strong relation (via FK) between a post entity and the user entity (the author of the post) since EF has no clue about this relation and no constraint will be generated during migration.

So what would happen if a user gets deleted and the Id reused for another user?

I'm also worried about performance issue during complex queries, since the DB engine cannot rely on FKs indexing (depending on the used DB engine, of course).

I wonder if a domain user entity can be created and extended only in the infrastructure layer for identity functionality.

Is there a better approach, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using integers as userId's since this allows people to guess the next/ previous user, they could very easily find all the users (This won't be as much of an issue if you have a secure program, yet I still think it's a better solution to use GUIDS in case some bug/ oversight causes unwanted openings)

Comment: Also you are able to create relations inside entity framework. See [Link](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use int or long as user identifier.
Id won't get reused because DB engine will lookup for the last entry's ID value and create a  new one as it's successor.
Better yet you can Implement EF's UseHiLo() method for your UserId.